# How to stop g_main_loop_run properly?

Tags: c++, glib

I am using GLib for the first time. So, to understand how to use GLib APIs, I wrote following dummy program.

```
#include<glib.h>

#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class executor
{
private:
        GMainLoop* main_loop;
        GMainContext* worker_context;
        thread worker_thread;

        void worker_loop()
        {
                g_main_context_push_thread_default(worker_context);
                cout << "Starting main loop" << endl;
                g_main_loop_run(main_loop);
                cout << "Finished main loop" << endl;
                g_main_context_pop_thread_default(worker_context);
        }

public:
        executor()
        {
                worker_context = g_main_context_new();
                main_loop = g_main_loop_new(worker_context, false);
                worker_thread = thread(&executor::worker_loop, this);
        }

        ~executor()
        {
                g_main_loop_quit(main_loop);
                cout << "Stopped main loop from running" << endl;
                g_main_loop_unref(main_loop);
                g_main_context_unref(worker_context);
                if (worker_thread.joinable())
                {
                        worker_thread.join();
                }
        }

        void queue_callback(int (*callback)(void))
        {
                GSource* idle_source = g_idle_source_new();
                g_source_set_callback(idle_source, (GSourceFunc)callback, NULL, NULL);
                g_source_attach(idle_source, worker_context);
                g_source_unref(idle_source);
        }
};

int func1()
{
        cout << "func1 started" << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
        cout << "func1 finished waiting" << endl;
        return 0;
}

int func2()
{
        cout << "func2 started" << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        cout << "func2 finished waiting" << endl;
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
        executor e;
        e.queue_callback(func1);
        e.queue_callback(func2);
        return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, it does not finish executing, it gets stuck. This is the output it prints.

```
Stopped main loop from running
Starting main loop
func1 started
func1 finished waiting
func2 started
func2 finished waiting
```

Sometimes it just fails with following error

```
Stopped main loop from running
Starting main loop

(process:16343): GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:58:54.405: g_main_loop_run: assertion 'g_atomic_int_get (&loop->ref_count) > 0' failed
Finished main loop
```

My guess is these both problems are happening because `g_main_loop_quit` and `g_main_loop_unref` run before `g_main_loop_run`. How do I fix these issues?

**EDIT after user7860670's comment:**
Thanks to user7860670 for the suggestion. Here is the working code now.

```
#include<glib.h>

#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class executor
{
private:
        GMainLoop* main_loop;
        GMainContext* worker_context;
        thread worker_thread;

        void worker_loop()
        {
                g_main_context_push_thread_default(worker_context);
                cout << "Starting main loop" << endl;
                g_main_loop_run(main_loop);
                cout << "Finished main loop" << endl;
                g_main_context_pop_thread_default(worker_context);
        }

public:
        executor()
        {
                worker_context = g_main_context_new();
                main_loop = g_main_loop_new(worker_context, false);
                worker_thread = thread(&executor::worker_loop, this);
        }

        ~executor()
        {
                cout << "Stopping main loop" << endl;
                GSource* idle_source = g_idle_source_new();
                g_source_set_callback(idle_source, (GSourceFunc)g_main_loop_quit, main_loop, NULL);
                g_source_attach(idle_source, worker_context);
                g_source_unref(idle_source);

                if (worker_thread.joinable())
                {
                        worker_thread.join();
                }
                cout << "Removing references to main loop and context" << endl;

                g_main_loop_unref(main_loop);
                g_main_context_unref(worker_context);
        }

        void queue_callback(int (*callback)(void))
        {
                GSource* idle_source = g_idle_source_new();
                g_source_set_callback(idle_source, (GSourceFunc)callback, NULL, NULL);
                g_source_attach(idle_source, worker_context);
                g_source_unref(idle_source);
        }
};

int func1()
{
        cout << "func1 started" << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
        cout << "func1 finished waiting" << endl;
        return 0;
}

int func2()
{
        cout << "func2 started" << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        cout << "func2 finished waiting" << endl;
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
        executor e;
        e.queue_callback(func1);
        e.queue_callback(func2);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `executor e;` may go out of scope prior to worker thread starting to work and since at the `~executor()` you are unrefing loop and context objects prior to waiting for worker thread their reference count drops to 0 and they are getting destroyed prior to working thread working. You should do it other way around: wait for a worker thread to finish and only then unref loop and context objects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I made change to the code above as per your suggestion. I think this will fix the assertion. However, the program still does not stop executing because I think `g_main_loop_quit` still happens before `g_main_loop_run`. I cannot move `g_main_loop_quit` after thread join because `g_main_loop_run` is a blocking call, so, join would never return, `g_main_loop_quit` would never execute and the thread would never stop.

Comment: @jyotesh If you want worker thread to quit only after executing `func1` and `func2` then you should enqueue `g_main_loop_quit` invocation after them instead of invoking it directly.